# jQuery as temporary polyfill

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, polyfills

I am writing a JavaScript that currently needs to support older browsers (like IE 7), until all users upgrade to a more modern browser next year.

I was thinking about using jQuery as a temporary polyfill, like this:

```
var flag=0;
window.JSON||(flag=1);
document.querySelectorAll||(flag=1);
if (flag===1) {
    // load jQuery here
}
else {
    // no need for jQuery
}
```

Does this approach make sense? Is there a better way?

The live demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/3mzxr/

Comment: What are you writing exactly? Jquery isn't just for json - it has many other capabilities and can compensate for browser crappiness quite nicely in most cases.

Comment: I don´t sure about what do you want do. If do you want detect the browser of the user and make change in your code. Use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: @Rup good point, I'll also need to write wrapper functions like myJSON=window.JSON||$.JSON

Comment: @MarcB I mainly need JSON and DOM selector. In my case the other jQuery functions don't bring much value and eventually I don't want to be tied to a specific library.

Comment: @humaknight browser detection is not enough, feature availability also depends on the doctype. And the point is that I want to detect it BEFORE loading jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entire approach is quite reasonable. You don't always need to use jQuery though.

For selectors functionality, you can use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) (5KB minified and gzipped) directly, without need for entire jQuery (30+ KB) that uses Sizzle as selectors engine. (Be careful though, that Sizzle itself has longstanding [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5637) related to inability to use boolean-attribute selector like `[autofocus]`. for some reason, the bug is worked around on jQuery level instead of fixing it on Sizzle level.)

For JSON, you can use [pure-JS JSON implementation](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (2.5 KB).

Also, it's generally better to detect features directly (checking `window.JSON` object for JSON and `document.querySelectorAll` for `qSA`) without assuming that supporting `JSON` means having support for `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: I believe that's what my code does, detect features individually? I understand the benefits of specific libraries, but loading them separately also has a cost. jQuery seemed like a good compromise.

Comment: According to your code, both absence of `window.JSON` or `document.querySelectorAll` lead to same `1` value of `flag`. As for separate files, nothing prevents you from joining two JS libraries into one single file; total size will be much smaller (~7.5 KB) than size of jQuery (~32 KB).

Comment: It's generally enough to just make sure that there is a new line (line feed) between code fragments of separate libs.

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not do this.

Use polyfills if that is what you want, it can easily be done with loaders like [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) and specific polyfill scripts for what you want to polyfill.

Comment: Optional jQuery seemed like a good compromise in my case. I am concerned with the cost of multiple http requests (first yepnope mandatory, then possibly a couple polyfills).